# Mongoose pre hook findOneAndUpdate to modify document before saving

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using the mongoose `pre` hook for `findOneAndUpdate`. I went through the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) to understand better it's usage. I would like to update the `password` field before it saves to DB. However, I am not getting the disired result - nothing gets changed. What would be the right approach for using the `findOneAndUpdate` pre hook to modify a certain field in the doc?

Actual Document

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("622457f5555562da89b7a1dd"),
  id: '5982ca552aeb2b12344eb6cd',
  name: 'Test User',
  configuration: [
    {
      email: 'test2@gmail.com',
      password: 'p@ssw0rd',
      _id: new ObjectId("9473l58f2ad34efb816963dd"),
    },
    {
      email: 'test3@gmail.com',
      password: 'trUstN0oNe',
      _id: new ObjectId("8674884cec1877c59c8838e0")
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

Desired Document

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("622457f5555562da89b7a1dd"),
  id: '5982ca552aeb2b12344eb6cd',
  name: 'Test User',
  configuration: [
    {
      email: 'test2@gmail.com',
      password: '0f359740bd1cda994f8b55330c86d845',
      _id: new ObjectId("9473l58f2ad34efb816963dd"),
    },
    {
      email: 'test3@gmail.com',
      password: '3dba7872281dfe3900672545356943ce',
      _id: new ObjectId("8674884cec1877c59c8838e0")
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

Code:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
   id: {
       type: String,
       required: [true, "'id' value is required"]
   },
   name: {
       type: String,
       required: [true, "'name' value is required"]
   },
   configuration: [ConfigModel.schema]
});

const ConfigSchema = new Schema({
   email: {
       type: String,
       required: [true, "Email is required"]
   },
   password: {
       type: String,
       required: [true, "Password is required"]
   }
});


UserSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function(next) {
   const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());

   docToUpdate.configuration.forEach((item,i) => {
      docToUpdate.configuration[i].password = md5(item.password);
   });
   return next();
});
```

Comment: You're using `docToUpdate.botconfiguration` while the property is called `configuration`.

Comment: @robertklep sorry about that. Correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `.save()` document command after changing the information inside the document, because you are only using `findOne`

```
const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());
    
docToUpdate.botconfiguration.forEach((item,i) => {
  docToUpdate.configuration[i].password = md5(item.password);
});
await docToUpdate.save() // <---- this line
```

You dont need the `updateMany()` here because the `ConfigSchema` is nested inside the user collection

Comment: This seems to work. Only thing is that it only updates the first configuration and not the second. Why is that?

Comment: Must be the `forEach` loop , usually this function does not work properly with asynchronous code. Also you are declaring the document to update as constant must be as variable `let` 

Is better destructure the configuration

`let { configuration } = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());`

 and then use the `for of` loop

`for (const item of configuration ) {
item.password = md5(item.password) }` 

 finally update all the configuration with the findOneAndUpdate.

`await this.model.findOneAndUpdate(this.getQuery(),{configuration})`

Answer (score 0):

in userModel you read configuration from ConfigModel so you have to modify the config model not user model it just read and populate the data from config model.

Comment: I think I follow. Could you show me in code please